# Android NDK Save file

Tags: android, file, android-ndk

This is a description of my problem:

**What I want to do:**

I have an app that I want to create a common **cpp** abstraction to a StorageManager class that will handle saving and loading files, for both my IOS app and my Android.

In order to do that, I need to save a file from cpp.

---

**What I would have wanted:**

I would want some NDK api to save files
Like there is, for example, an API for logging:

```
#include <android/log.h>
__android_log_print(Tag, Msg);
```

I want something like:

```
NativeStorageManager__save_file_to_internal_storage(File file, string fileName);
```

---

**The problem:**

From what I read in this documentation: http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#assets
I don't see such simple API.

The only thing I see is getting the internal storage path from a NativeActivity:

```
nativeActivity->internalDataPath;
```

But I don't have a NativeActivity...
Nor the main function to get the NativeActivity:

```
void android_main(struct android_app* state)
```

---

**So my questions are:**

1. Am I correct and there is no such API?
2. Is my only option to call Java using JNI in order to retrieve the path to the internal storage and then save the file in this path from the cpp code?
3. Do you think 2 is a reasonable solution?
4. I saw that in the Java API there are some options to save files:
   Context.MODE_PRIVATE
   Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE
   etc...

From:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref
"By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user)"

When I save a file in cpp using:

```
std::fopen(fileNameAndPath, "w+");
```

Will it save it in Context.MODE_PRIVATE by default?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: `__save_file_to_internal_storage(File file, string fileName);` ?? Why that File parameter? I think you would something more like `__save_text_to_internal_storage(String text, string fileName);`. You can save to internal, external and sometimes to removable media.

Comment: Yes, your version would be a better version.
Do you know of a method such as this existing??

Comment: You can code that in a few lines. Has been posted many times on this site. Just google for it.

Comment: Searched, haven't seen a solution that doesn't use JNI

Comment: You searched wrong then. Just open a FileOutputStream to write. Ok that will not be there. Then use fopen() and fwrite() and so.

Comment: You mean FileOutputStream the java method??

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the mistake. Use fopen(), fwrite() and fclose().

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, 
And that would automatically save to the file to:
/data/data/<my_package_name>/files?
And if I would like to save it to the cache folder:
/data/data/<my_package_name>/cache

I would have to call JNI to get the cache path?

Also what about the permissions? so it would be like Context.MODE_PRIVATE?

Comment: Don't know. But that is simple to test i would think. For the rest i have no experience with NDK but i would think that these are basics you can find with some searching. Context.MODE_PRIVATE for fopen() ? Don't understand.